# method template specialization by return type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a class with template method that the parameter defines the return type. The default constructor for everything else is ok, but for bool I would like the method to return true. I am trying to specialize it as the following code, but this does not compile.

```
class Foo {
    template <class T>
    T method() {
        ...
        return T();
    }

    template<>
    bool method() {
       ...
       return true;
    }

};
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specialize inside a class scope. According to the C++ standard,

> **14.7.3/2** An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template.

Therefore you should specialize the template member function at namespace scope,

```
template<> // this should be outside the primary template class definition
bool Foo::method() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why that makes a difference?

Comment: @s.bandara those are the rules. As to why they are so, I don't really know, that's how it was decided when formally defining the language. The compiler complains: `error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Foo'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use SFINAE to achieve the desired effect, which technically turns the "specialization" (which is not possible as the other answer explained) into an overload:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<
    ! std::is_same< T, bool >::value,
    T
>::type
method() {
    ...
    return T();
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same< T, bool >::value,
    T
>::type
method() {
    ...
    return true;
}
```

The above is C++11, with C++14 you can even use `std::enable_if_t` to make it shorter.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9401a142315032d)